# Why My game is not switching in between Scenes in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a game. It has 3 scenes, A menu scene, A level and a Congrats Scene. I have added all of them in the build settings in order which is shown below,

[image: image description here]

but when I press play, the error I have show below occurs. Although the code is alright, no errors in the code but every time I press play, unity spits out an error which is shown below:

[image: image description here]

Comment: Could the space be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the script associated to your play button.

you are trying to load `Leve One` scene, but your scene is called `Level One`. So you should fix that typo in your script.